# cron jobs to upload a file via FTP

Tags: scripting, ftp, automation, cron

Is it possible to use CRON to upload a file via FTP? If yes how can I call FTP to run an upload?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming a UNIX-like operating system you could setup a cron job that pointed to a shell script like the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd [source directory]
ftp -n [destination host]<<END
user [user] [password]
put [source file]
quit
END
```

Depending on your ftp client defaults and the source file type you may need to specify `binary` prior to the `put`.

Answer (score 2):

You may use ncftp -- they have an handy tools called "ncftpput"

It is easier then using expect -- it is just a single command with useful return code.

Answer (score 1):

You probably are looking for a program called "expect" which is designed for dealing with interactive processes.

http://expect.nist.gov/

If you have "cron", you likely already have "expect" as well, these days.

Answer (score 1):

Schedule a script call from `cron`.
In the script,

- Use [Public Key Authentication](http://www.ssh.com/support/documentation/online/ssh/adminguide/32/Public-Key_Authentication-2.html) to open a [Secure FTP](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sftp) communication with your server
- Execute a batch file of `PUT`s to your server (there is a `-b` option in `sftp`)

For this,

- you will need to setup the public key authentication between the server and your client,machine.
- you will need a `sftp` client on the client machine (there are clients for all platforms -- PuTTY, Winscp.net, unix variants usually have this already installed).
- finally, try the PUT manually with public key authentication and note down the commands -- you can write them down in to the batch file for automation

---

Some other notes.

- `expect` is an overkill for this requirement.
- More over, any scheme that requires the password to be scripted is bad
- `ncftp` is good for an interactive session (not such automation)
- I do not know if `wput` allows public key authentication (probably not), in which case its not good for such automation either

Answer (score 0):

Just create your CRON jobs to call WGET to upload or download your file via FTP!

Comment: Actually, you'd rather want to use wput(http://wput.sourceforge.net/) to put stuff on the remote server.